# CSS span with border

Tags: html, css

Hi i don't get why my span with border looks like this

[image]

this is the css behind

```
color:red; 
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #ffcaca;
background-image:url(/Content/x.png);
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:2px;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px;
border: 1px solid red;
padding-left: 25px;
position:relative;
```

and html

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>[...]</span>
    <td>
<tr>
```

Comment: How should it look then? In one line?

Comment: one line or an entire box, this looks like someone cut the box

Comment: give `display: block` to the span.

Comment: @theLaw Better to use a `<div>` element instead, if you don't need an inline wrapper.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can give `display: block` to the span element or use `div` element instead of using `span` element.

I would prefer the latter one.

Answer (score 4):

if you are stuck in a wordpress theme because you don't want to touch to the template and you just want to add custom css, using `display: block` or `display: inline-block` will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use border style for this. apply border style and then get the border styling on the span element.